# Using the Random() class with enhanced for loops

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Enhanced for loops are weird. Why does

```
int size = 10;
Random random = new Random();
int[] scores = new int[size];

for (int score : scores) {
    scores[score] = random.nextInt(size);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scores));
```

Give me a mostly empty array where only the first element is the random number,
whilst:

```
int size = 10;
Random random = new Random();
int[] scores = new int[size];

for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
    scores[i] = random.nextInt(size);
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scores));
```

gives me what I want: a 10-element array composed of random digits?
I thought the two loops were substitutions of each other; but when it comes to the Random(), it's only the first element that gets altered?

Comment: Enhanced for loop has no indices. You can view it equivalent to some kind of `Iterator<X> iter = iterable.iterator(); while (iter.hasNext()) { X element = iter.next(); }`. That is also why it supports everything of type `Iterable`. There are iterable elements that have no index per definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enhanced for loop:

```
for (int score : scores)
```

iterates over the values of the array, not the indices.

When you instantiate the array with `int[] scores = new int[size]`, The values are all initialized to `0` by default.

Therefore:

```
scores[score] = random.nextInt(size);
```

is always:

```
scores[0] = random.nextInt(size);
```

When you need to modify an array, you should use the traditional for loop, which iterates over the indices.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and explanation! 

I guess I'll now think of the differences as so:
with the conventional for (x;y;z) loops, I'll read it as usual "for the index in i, do this",
whilst with the enhanced for(x:y) loop, it's read more like "for the *actual values* in the array, do this". 

Coupled with the other explanations, it really helped give me an overall picture. I couldn't decide which answer to affirmatively 'tick', so as yours came first in the queue, I assume that answer came first.

Answer (score 3):

These are different constructs. Essentially with the first loop, you are saying "go get all of the elements of `scores` and loop over them`. You don't get the index, you get the actual values which will always be`0` in your case!

```
for (int score : scores){
    // score is always 0!
    scores[score] = random.nextInt(size);
}
```

Your second loop, as you've figured out, gives you the index (`i`) rather than the value in the `scores` array.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and explanation! Coupled with the other explanations, it really helped give me an overall picture. I couldn't decide which answer to affirmatively 'tick', so I ticked the answer that came first in the queue, as I assume that answer came first.

Comment: Glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different loops actually,

```
 for (int score : scores){
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
```

First one gives the `value` of array (not an index of specified array) whereas second gives the `index`. As said, the meaning changes for below code

```
scores[score] = random.nextInt(size);
```

So, imagine your array has value `1,2,5`, so you would basically accessing index `1`, `2` and `5` in first loop, on the other hand, second loop assigning value to specific index, which goes with `0`, `1` and `2`.

Since `scores` was initialized with default values `0`, so in each iteration, it was updating value at the `0`th index.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and explanation! Coupled with the other explanations, it really helped give me an overall picture. I couldn't decide which answer to affirmatively 'tick', so I ticked the answer that came first in the queue, as I assume that answer came first.

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you have a misconception about the enhanced loop in Java, because it is a foreach loop and iterates over the values of the array, not over the keys:

Look at the following example

```
String[] my_string_array = new String[]{"Dog","House","Cat"};
for(String s: my_string_array){
    System.out.println(s); //prints "Dog", then "House", then "cat" 
    //s equals one entry of the Array
}
```

In your example, every entry of the array is 0, because this is the default value for integers. 
So in each repetition of your array, the following happens

```
scores[0] = random.nextInt(size);
```

I hope you understand the problem with your first code.
Just use the first one, it is working and best practise.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, explanation and example! Coupled with the others, it really helped give me an overall picture. Your example was particularly illuminating. I couldn't decide which answer to affirmatively 'tick', so I ticked the answer that came first in the queue, as I assume that answer came first.